# django form choice field refresh

Tags: django, forms, postgresql

I have a choice field on a form which allows the user to select a table from within my postgres database. Using the development server this is populated during the runserver command. The problem I have is I would like the choice field to update with new tables which may be created by user. At present the only way to make new tables available in the choice field is to start and stop the server. Is there a way this can be done automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a custom `__init__` method on your form. Call `super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`, and then set `self.fields["thechoicefield"].choices` when you initialize the form.